# Fetching data from an API - Console Repeats

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api, console.log

I am having a bit of trouble.

I need to create a website that will display three random Chuck Norris jokes using the following API: http://www.icndb.com/api/. I have to use the following URL to fetch the jokes: http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chuck Norris Jokes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Added a navigation bar to display logo. -->
    <nav class="navigation-bar">
        <img src="images/Logo.png" alt=Logo id="logo" />
    </nav>
    <!-- Created a container so I can set the grid sections. -->
    <div id="container">
        <!-- First container for the heading and the image. -->
        <div>
            <h1>Chuck Norris Jokes</h1>
            <img src="images/chuck.png" alt="Chuck Norris Armed" id="chuckshoot">
        </div>
        <!-- Second section for the text and for the button. -->
        <div id="jokegen">
            <div id="jokeTxt">
            <p id="j1"></p>
            <p id="j2"></p>
            <p id="j3"></p>
        </div>
            <button id="jokeBtn" value="fetch">Click Here For A Chuckle!</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My Javascript is as follows:

```
// Created an array for the Chuck Norris jokes.
let joke = [];
// Attached an event handler to the button.
document.getElementById('jokeBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    // Fetching the API.
    fetch("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3")
        // Grabbing the information from the JSON file.
        .then(res => res.json())
        // Fetching the joke from value in JSON.
        .then(function (result) {
            for (let i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
            jokes = result.value[0].joke;
            jokes2 = result.value[1].joke;
            jokes3 = result.value[2].joke;

            console.log(jokes);
            console.log(jokes2);
            console.log(jokes3);
            console.log(typeof joke);
            // Displaying the fetched jokes in HTML.
            document.getElementById("j1").innerHTML = jokes;
            document.getElementById("j2").innerHTML = jokes2;
            document.getElementById("j3").innerHTML = jokes3;
            }
        }),
        // If the above could not be executed and an error should occur.
        error => {
            console.log(error + "");
        };
})
```

The HTML is showing correctly but in console all three jokes appear even if I call a single joke. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You are looping over all three jokes, and inside the loop, you log all three jokes to console every time. Three times three was still nine last time I checked.

Comment: You iterate through all jokes, and for each console.log all three jokes, so it is what you get.
you need ether use `value[0]`, `value[1]` and `value[2]` without iteration, or iterate though values and use `value[i]` and `document.getElementById("j"+(i+1)).innerHTML = value[i]`

Comment: Thank you both for your help. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the Javascript a little and use a `forEach` loop on the `value` property within the response.

The `error => {console.log(error + "")}` piece is not quite right - that should be within a `catch` segment - ie `.catch( err=>console.log(err) )` or similar

```js
document.getElementById( 'jokeBtn' ).addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  fetch( 'https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/3' )
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( json => {
      if( json.type=='success' ){
        json.value.forEach( ( obj, i )=>{
          let node=document.getElementById( 'j' + ( i + 1 ) );
          if( node )node.innerHTML=obj.joke;
        })
      }
    })
})
```

```html
<nav class="navigation-bar">
  <img src="images/Logo.png" alt=Logo id="logo" />
</nav>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Chuck Norris Jokes</h1>
    <img src="images/chuck.png" alt="Chuck Norris Armed" id="chuckshoot">
  </div>
  <div id="jokegen">
    <div id="jokeTxt">
      <p id="j1"></p>
      <p id="j2"></p>
      <p id="j3"></p>
    </div>
    <button id="jokeBtn" value="fetch">Click Here For A Chuckle!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution is working wonderfully. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Pleasure - glad that it helped! Good luck